# How can i find salary is more than the average salary of every staff

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to view rows from my table where the salary is more than the average salary of every staff member. With the code below it it giving me an error:

> Operand data type varchar is invalid for avg operator.

```
SELECT StaffID, StaffName, LEFT(StaffGender, 1)  AS [Staff Gender], 
'Rp. ' + CAST ((StaffSalary)AS VARCHAR) [Staff Salary]
FROM MsStaff
WHERE StaffName Like '% %' AND StaffSalary > AVG(StaffSalary)
```

Update: 
I have changed the `StaffSalary` column to `INT` datatype, but I get another error:

> Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 48
>   An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery
>  contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is
>  an outer reference."

[image: Data sample]

Comment: Well, it sounds like `StaffSalary` is a varchar type. You need to cast it to a numeric type. That said, that SQL just isn't right. You need to get the avg in a subquery and then use it. See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_avg.asp for an example.

Comment: What datatype is your `StaffSalary` column? `AVG()` works on numeric types. If `StaffSalary` is not numeric, why not? It should be. Let me guess... You stored it with a currency symbol and thousands separators, like `$25,000`, right? That's confusing presentation with data.

Comment: Appears that its considering StaffSalary as type of varchar when evaluating average.

Comment: show some sample data of your msstaff table.. especially the stafsalary column data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it seems to makes sense, you can’t use `AVG()` like that.
Use a sub-query to find the average:

```
SELECT ...
FROM MsStaff
WHERE StaffName Like '% %'
AND StaffSalary > (SELECT AVG(StaffSalary) FROM MsStaff)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from MsStaff where StaffSalary > (select avg(StaffSalary) from MsStaff)
```